# LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE phpmyadmin Error #1064

Tags: mysql, xml, phpmyadmin, load

I've to import an XML file with inconsistent Column Names into my database.
I use this SQL:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'serer.org/folders/file.xml' 
INTO TABLE Original_xml
        SET codiceproduttore = Cod., 
        categoria_merceologica_primaria = Categoria, 
        categoria_merceologica_secondaria = Sottocategoria,
        disponibilita_sede = Q.tà disponibile,
        ean = Cod. a barre,
        sconto = extra 1,
        prezzo_netto = Prezzo forn.
```

When I execute the query in phpmyadmin, it returns this error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'XML LOCAL INFILE 'labotinfo.zapto.org/Web/gestionale/listini/brvlist_10012015095' at line 1

Do I have to enable the LOAD "module" in php.ini? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First, since you're using phpMyAdmin, why aren't you using the Import tab directly? You should be able to import your XML file there graphically instead.

Anyway, no, this isn't related to php.ini.

Your syntax is a bit wrong. `LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE` looks for a local file on the client, not a URL. I don't remember what exactly phpMyAdmin would try to do in this case with the LOCAL directive, particularly if your webserver isn't on the local machine (in which case the webserver is technically the client to MySQL, not your local machine). I suggest uploading to the server and not using LOCAL because of this unknown factor. The proper use of the LOCAL directive is further explained in the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html).